# Can we add our DataSet(Images) to ML5 Data Model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-recognition, tensorflow.js

We are using ml5js, its a high-level interface to TensorFlow.js, a library for handling GPU-accelerated mathematical operations and memory management for machine learning algorithms.
We are using 'imageClassifier' and 'featureExtractor' methods to recognize images using ml5-library. We have successfully recognized the images with your Pre-trained model.
Now we want to add our Data set(Images with its label) in ml5 data model. We are using addImage(Image, Label) function to add an image, but its take references of following lines:

// Create a new classifier using those features and with a video element

const classifier = featureExtractor.classification(video, videoReady);

We could not able to understand the uses and flow of the featureExtractor.classification() function and got some exception relatively.
Please let us know if we are doing anything wrong here or need some additional steps to achieve this.

Thank you,

Comment: Welcome to SO; please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you please show the code and the exception you got ?